# assign a constant after filter in React js

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I want to assign a constant to an array with a specific key.

```
"main": [
    {
        "1": [
            {
                "[\"test\"]": {},
                "[\"match\"]": {}
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "2": [
            {
                "[\"test\"]": {},
                "[\"match\"]": {}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried this way, but it did not help

```
 const dates = main.filter(main.key === info.key);
```

Please tell me how this can be done? Do I understand correctly that '1' and '2' in main are keys?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please post the desired result?
It will help to solve

Comment: you are using the filter syntax incorrectly

Comment: I want the object 1 or 2 to be assigned entirely to the constant after the filter of main.key = info.key. the best solution for me would be a dynamic change of the constant, the variable info.key may change

Comment: Do you want them in an array or some different constants?

Comment: In the array. Then I want to spend with him a few actions, but this is another story :)